# Why do I get "no previous prototype for function" in this little sample?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a very simple Objective-C sample

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int littleFunction();

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool 
    = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

int littleFunction()
{
    return 0;
}
```

With this code I get a "no previous prototype for function" warning for littleFunction but as you can all see there is a declaration before main. What is wrong here? It seem the compiler is unable to match the declaration with the function implementation.

If I change both like this:

```
int littleFunction(void)
```

it works perfectly.
I am using the latest Xcode 4

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In C, `int littleFunction();` is not *really* a prototype. It doesn't specify how many (or what sort of) parameters the function accepts.

The actual wording in C99 is in §6.7.5.3 item 14:

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. The **empty list** in a function declarator *that is not part of a definition of that function* specifies that **no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied**.<sup>124</sup>

The footnote refers to this section in the *Future language directions*:

> **6.11.6 Function declarators**
>   The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
>   type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

(Note: this is still present in the C11 draft I have (n1570).)

Back in §6.7.5.3, item 10:

> The special case of an unnamed parameter of type `void` as the only item in the list
>   specifies that the function has no parameters.

So you have to explicitly specify `int foo(void);` if you want to prototype a function that doesn't take parameters. Objective-C has the same rules.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is that you did not use "static" for a **global** function.

Please refer to the following:

no previous prototype for `foo'

This means that GCC found a global function definition without seeing a prototype for the function. If a function is used in more than one file, there should be a prototype for it in a header file somewhere. This keeps functions and their uses from getting out of sync

If the function is only used in this file, make it **static** to guarantee that it'll never be used outside this file and document that it's a local function

Comment: This is the real answer.